# Preallocate very large array in Python leads to MemoryError

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, memory

I am trying to preallocate a list in python

```
c=[1]*mM #preallocate array
```

My Problem is that I run in to a MemoryError since

```
mM=4999999950000000
```

What is the best way to deal with this. I am thinking about creating a new object where is split my list at about a value of `500000000`.
Is this what I should do or is there a best practice to create an array with a lot of inputs?

Comment: You need some 5 Petabytes of memory to store this.

Comment: Yes. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Also if you're on Linux then you can do something like [this with memory swapping.](http://www.napuzba.com/story/extend-memory-swap/)

Comment: what's your actual problem. why do you need to create a array/list of size : 4999999950000000 ?? As pointed out. this will need 5PB of storage space..

Comment: If you assume an integer in Python is 4 bytes (the amount of memory consumed by one integer may increase dramatically when needed), you'd need more that 20 __petabytes__ of memory to store that data.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ Actually, on a 64bit system you need *40 petabytes* for this. Just for the underlying array in the `list` object: `4999999950000000 *1e-9*8`, plus the Python overhead, plus the extra space....

Comment: @ForceBru actually, you need to account for the integers *and their pointers, which what the array underlying the list actually holds*. So, on a 64-bit system, that is 8 bytes per pointer, so 40 petabytes just for the array of pointers. And actually, A python `int` object is more like 28-24 byes. So ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using a Generator

You are attempting to create an object that you **very likely** will not be able to fit into your computer's memory. If you truly need to represent a list of that length, you can use a generator that dynamically produces values as they are needed.

```
def ones_generator(length):
    for _ in range(length):
        yield 1

gen = ones_generator(4999999950000000)
for i in gen:
    print(i)  # prints 1, a lot
```

**Note:** The question is tagged for Python 3, but if you are using Python 2.7, you will want to use `xrange` instead of `range`.

### Using a Dictionary

By the sound of your question, you do not actually need to preallocate a list of that length, but you want to store values very sparsely at indexes that are very large. This pattern matches the `dict` type in Python more so than the `list`. You can simply store values in a dictionary, without pre-allocating they keys/space, Python handles that under the hood for you.

```
dct = {}
dct[100000] = "A string"
dct[592091] = 123
dct[4999999950000000] = "I promise, I need to be at this index"

print(dct[4999999950000000])
# I promise, I need to be at this index
```

In that example, I just stored `str` and `int` values, but they can be any object in Python. The best part about this is that this dictionary will not consume memory based on the maximum index (like a `list` would) but instead based on how many values are stored within it.

Comment: The question is tagged Python 3, so you don't have `xrange` is just `range`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I updated the answer to include a note about python version.

Comment: Ok since I really do not have the 5 Petabytes i prefer your solution with the dict. I really just need defined values at certain locations